# Python - ssh and sftp through a middle computer

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

Device 1 is connected to Device 2 over my network. Device 2 is also connect to Device 3, which is not directly connected to Device 1. From Device 1, I would like to be able to send files to either Device 2 or Device 3.

Currently, I am using paramiko to establish an ssh connection and then using sftp to put the files on Device 2 from Device 1. This is not a problem.

What is the best way to transfer files to Device 3, using Device 2 as a middle man? I know I could copy to Device 2 and then somehow copy again to Device 3, but this seems inefficient. How should I go about linking Device 1 to Device 3 so I can simply use `sftp.put()`?

I cannot change the network configuration, so please do not suggest that.

Comment: I would take a look at [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

Comment: Is there something specific to Fabric that would help me here? @wilbur

Comment: Well I personally don't know a way that you can link Device 1 directly to Device 3 with python, so if you created a fabric task that copied the files over, you can run it on Device 1 with the destination as Device 2and subsequently on Device 2 with the destination as Device 3. Sorry I can't think of a more elegant way to do it right now

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of fabric, but that same idea was essentially my backup. I think there is some method to setup a tunnel. Hopefully it integrates well with paramiko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use SSH Tunnel,
There are different options:

1. [sshtunnel](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel): `pip install sshtunnel`
2. Use para as forwarder port: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py

Sample:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())

try:
    client.connect(server[0], server[1], username=options.user, key_filename=options.keyfile,            look_for_keys=options.look_for_keys, password=password)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I didn't think of tunnelling until responding to wilbur. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just do confirm, what is `server` in your example? Just `[hostname, port]`? And your example doesn't establish the tunnel does it? @Ali Nikneshan

Comment: server = (Device2,Port2). Check the link for full example, I just extract the interesting part.